# Create a serializer for custom user model in django-rest-auth?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I've installed django-rest-framework. Also i've installed django allauth.
Now i want to use django-rest-auth based on previous two, for serializing data
and sending it in json format as answer on my submit form method (for registration/login etc).
I look up into documentation is provided [for django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)
but it feels for me strange, as i inherit(and must do so) from the `AbstractBaseUser` and not simply do `OneToOneField` on existing User model.
At the moment the model i assign to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my settings.py is:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Account Email')

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

The question is: how can i use serializing in rest-auth the same way, but using my model instead of provided `UserProfile` model example ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may inherit it, and use serializers the way you are saying. It should work. Please state where the error arises when you are using serializers for this.